# Getting Bitmap of all the Views in ViewFlipper in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery, viewflipper

I need to take the Bitmap of all the Views in ViewFlipper. But it
gives me the Bitmap of only the current content on the screen. Is
there any way of getting Bitmap of all the Views in the ViewFlipper.

Or is there any other way around to get the Bitmap of all the Views. I
have four views and need to load them at the same time and get their
Bitmap so that I can resize it and later display with Gallery.

I hope to get a quick response this time around.

Comment: Solved it by setting the visibility of all the views to visible.

Comment: Interesting... so your bitmap is a snapshot of all views in the flipper - sort of a ultra wide (panoramic) picture?

Comment: Yes, needed to do that since the requirement was a view similar to Iphone Safari and TweetDeck in iphone.